# Any way to save a spot on a webpage

Tags: browser-addons, google-chrome-extensions, bookmarks, webpage

If an article is a long read sometimes I want to save my spot on a webpage not the whole page itself. Are there any extensions/apps/plugins/addons to do this? Focus is on windows and google chrome

Answer (score 0):

**This method involves saving the whole page :**

[Pocket](http://getpocket.com) help people save interesting articles, videos and more from the web for later enjoyment.This application saves the section on each article where we stopped reading and present us with that section when we reopen the article later.Much better , this syncs across all devices.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer, (kind of a workaround) but many web pages contain a directory in the masthead. If you are at a place to which you want to return later or refer someone, and there is an existing link to that section in the web page, you can copy that link address and edit your bookmark to have that navigation detail.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try opening chrome app store and scroll down to "Annotate the Web."  The app I am trying is called Weava Highlighter .

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you expand your answer a bit? It's better to include some instructions on how to use the product to solve the problem, or at least describe what makes the product a good solution, providing value beyond a random Google hit. Good guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.